# Apache Camel create basic authentication header from plain text

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Camel. I have a working project that receives a request in one format, then route it to a different server. As part of this routing, I need to create the authentication header using a combination of username and password.

The result header should be (I have generated the base64 manually, and hard-coded for now):

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="Authorization"><camel:simple>Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=</camel:simple></camel:setHeader>
```

So, I need a way to transform a combination of plain username + password into base64, and add them into Camel configuration. Please note I don't have Java code in the application, only XML code.

Thank you!

Comment: What producer type are you using? camel-http(4)?

Comment: And I seriously hope that `admin:admin` are not your actual credentials. ;-)

Comment: admin:admin is used only for test purposes. I am using camel-http, but also tried with camel-http4. I would like to have an example of how to set the basic authentication information for a SOAP call.

Comment: http4 seems to support basic auth via query parameters `authUsername` and `authPassword`, and `authenticationPreemptive=true`.

Comment: I've tried submitting those details, but didn't work. When sending explicitly the Authorization header it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the **Groovy** language to populate the `Authorization` header, eg:

```
.setHeader("Authorization").groovy(myExpr)
```

As far as I known, Groovy's GDK provides methods to Base64-encode strings:

```
def s = 'userid:password'
String encoded = s.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
```

Comment: Now I am trying to inject the properties username and password inside Groovy script, do you know how that works?


`<camel:setProperty propertyName="password"><camel:xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//xls:XLS/xls:_Header/@clientPassword</camel:xpath></camel:setProperty>
  <camel:setProperty propertyName="username"><camel:xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//xls:XLS/xls:_Header/@clientName</camel:xpath></camel:setProperty>
<camel:setHeader headerName="Authorization"><camel:groovy>'Basic '+'admin:admin'.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()</camel:groovy></camel:setHeader>
`

Comment: Like this: 
<groovy>"${exchange.properties[<your-key>]}"</groovy>

Comment: Thanks! I have finally managed to make it working with HTTP properties for authentication